# Pivot table on mutiple pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have large data splitted into 5 dataframes with exactly same rows.
Just wondering, if there any efficient way to merge the pivot tables
and to process them in parallel.

Process that would like to do is :

```
df1 --> df1_pivot   ---> Merge(df1_pivot, df2_pivot) ---> df1_df2_pivot
df1 --> df2_pivot
```

Goal is to process dataframe in parallel and merge them.
(using multi-processing).

EDIT:  Pivot can be multi-index, like this.

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, index= ['col4', 'col3' ], columns=[ 'col1', 'col2' ],  
                          values='val_tosum', aggfunc='sum' )
```

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5], axis=1)
```

Comment: but there multi-level index on rows and columns size.

Comment: @Tensor huh!?  interesting... I didn't see that in the question.  Maybe you can provide some of that information.